# How to make Snakemake wrappers work with the {threads} variable

Tags: snakemake

EDIT 27-07-2018: Wrapper does not account for threads. Furthermore, the syntax I`m trying here won't work and as far as I can find similar syntax is not supported. Answer is from cross-post on Snakemake Google groups and meono below.

I am using Snakemake and I'm quite happy with it. However, for some processes I`m using wrappers (i.e. FastQC and Trimmomatic). However, I notice that these wrappers do not take the {threads} variable into account. Can someone explain what the proper syntax is to make this work?

I've tried setting `threads: 4` and then specifying `{threads}` at the proper place in the code (e.g. for FastQC: `params: "--threads {threads}"`). Likewise, I've tested setting `{wildcards.threads}` and also `{snakemake.threads}`. It looks like that wrapper codeblock is unable to "see" the value of the threads variable.

Please see the example below.

Note: I've looked at the Bitbucket snakemake-wrapper repo and readthedocs readme, but could not find an answer.

```
rule FastQC_preTrim:
input:
    join(RAW_DATA, PATTERN_ANY)
output:
    html="FastQC_pretrim/{sample}.html",
    zip="FastQC_pretrim/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
threads: 4
params:
    "--threads {wildcards.threads}"   # Also tried {threads}
wrapper:
    "0.20.1/bio/fastqc"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(would put this in a comment but don't have the reps)

[fastqc wrapper](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/fastqc.html) doesn't account for `threads` in rule. I think

```
params:
    "--threads 4"
```

would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while trying to use snakemake wrappers but failed when specifying {threads} or any other wildcards into params.

A workaround is to explicitly define a "thread" parameter in your config.yaml and calling it from there. For example:

```
# In config.yaml
thread_use: 32
```

And

```
# In rule
rule some_rule_with_wrapper:
    input:
        "path/to/input"
    output:
        "path/to/output"
    params:
        extra="-t "+str(config["thread_use"])  # Remember to coerce int to string
    threads: 32
    wrapper:
        "some/wrapper"
```